# minSdk(API 23)> deviceSdk(API 19)

Tags: android, android-studio

When I am trying to run the first program (HelloWorld) in Android Studio using the green run button, I am getting the following error:

> **minSdk(API 23)> deviceSdk(API 19) error**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2X11.png)

How do I fix it?

Comment: Just go to build.gradle(Module:app) and change minSdkVersion:16 or 17 .  
  or create new avd for latest version.

Answer (score 4):

You have set minimal SDK on your project is API 23 (marshmallow) and your device or emulator has SDK(API 19, Kitkat). Just go to build.gradle(Module:app) and change minSdkVersion:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "YOUR PACKAGE"
        minSdkVersion 17 //change here
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: API 19 is not installed on my machine.I am unable to make changes to SDK platforms.what could be the possible reason?

Comment: Are you sure? It said your device has API 19 (Based on screenshot). What API which installed on your device? I have told you possible answer. Your project have minSDK API 23 and your device have API 19. So, your device can not run the project @Ranga